# Updating all objects in the Immutable.js List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have:

```
const obj = {
  state: {
    products: [
      {id: 1, __open: true},
      {id: 1, __open: true},
      {id: 1, __open: true},
    ]
  }
}

const im = Immutable.fromJS(obj)
```

I need to remove `__open` from all products.

I have been trying few things but I can't get it working.

```
//val is List this is no no

im.updateIn(['state', 'products'], (val) => val.delete('__open'))
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't know what happen last night. Just in case anyone else will have a brain freeze:

```
im.updateIn(['state', 'products'], (val) => val.map(ele => ele.delete('__open')))
```

Comment: Very sleek. Good job!